# iCloud Document Library as replacement for Dropbox?

Tags: icloud

I've been put down by iCloud when it came out and kept using Dropbox instead. I mostly need to synch files between macs and eventually sneak-pick them on mobile devices. I don't take lots of pictures, I'm not an iWork user and most of all I need to share PDF files, Illustrator / Photoshop files and source files as I'm a programmer. Will the upcoming "iCloud Document Library" work like Dropbox allowing me to sync and share any kind of file even when not directly supported by an iCloud-linked app? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Maybe I didn't make it clear enough. I don't want to share my documents *with other people* I want to share them *among my devices*. The problem with iCloud as it is now is that it doesn't let me manage any kind of file that I like, but only certain formats, while I'd like to synch among my two macs, my iPad and my iPhone files like .zip files, .ai (Adobe Illustrator) files, .avi movies, source files of software I write and so on, hence not being limited to "sync photos" or "sync Pages document", since those are not kind of files that I'm interested in sharing among devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, as iCloud is supposed to be for personal use only. To, in this case, share documents between all **your** devices.

You could always share your password and let someone else log in and download the file, but that will be insecure, of course. Extracted from [Apple's iCloud page:](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/documents.html)

> Just sign in to [icloud.com/iwork](https://www.icloud.com/#iwork) in any modern web browser, and all your iWork for iOS documents will be there — complete with your most recent edits. Click a document to download it in iWork ’09, Microsoft Office, or PDF format

**Edit:** Documents eligible for sharing with this new feature, are those created or edited with compatible Apps. Therefore, I don't think you'll be able to share *any* kind of files through iCloud.

> iCloud is already seamlessly **integrated** with the Apple iWork apps for your iOS devices — Pages, Keynote, and Numbers. And we’ve given **developers the tools to make their apps work with iCloud, too**.

Comment: please, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

No, iCloud is your Apple device etcetera cloud. It syncs relevant data between your Apple devices and their desktop/iOS app equivalents. While you might be able to upload a zip-file or an .ai file to an iCloud folder, that is not its current intended use.

Everyone wants their own space on the web these days. Adobe's got their cloud, Microsoft got their 365. Still – the best solution is sticking to ye good old legacy *folder* and its *file*, aka. Dropbox et.al.

Short answer: Dropbox is currently a much better alternative for your needs.